# create new question if yes/no radio button selected c# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic

i have a question:

```
<div>
    Is hacking good?</div>
    <div>
        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="1question" runat="server" 
            RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
            <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:RadioButtonList>
    </div>
```

I want to add dynamicly new question if Yes/No is selected.

if yes/no || 1/0 selected, i'm calling Method GetQuestion(int questionId)..
this method returns me a text of next question.
this question schould be created dynamicly (javascript) as next. how to create it dynamicly??

How can i do that?

Comment: what are you calling a "new question" ?

Comment: i think what he meant was to display a new set of Yes/No questions as the user selects an answer

Comment: absolutely correct, it is my goal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First the new question can be all ready there but hidden, or just create all on the fly.

Let say that is there, but hidden.

```
<asp:Panel id="pnlSecondQuestion" runat="server" Visible="false" 
                   EnableViewState="false">
    <div>Is hacking ethical?</div>
    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="SecondQuestion" runat="server" 
        RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
        <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
</asp:Panel>
```

Now can be hidden of html part and open it with javascript, or totally hidden and open it with the code behind.

- If you make it `Visible="false"`  then on click of the first question you make autopostback, and you just open this one `pnlSecondQuestion.Visible=true` In this case to avoid the full page refresh you can use an UpdatePanel warp all your questions.
- If you make it hidden with css `style="display:none"`, then you make a javasript function that is make it visible when the user click on the first question `onclick="return makeitvisible()"`

Now if you with to make the full question on the fly, then you use a PlaceHolder, and you dynamically create your question on code behind, but this is a little more dificult.

Hope this help.

Comment: +1, that would work for one question. however, if you want something more dynamic, bind the example above in a Repeater then bind the questions to that repeater to display all your questions.

Comment: can ID start with a digit? =)

Comment: @Martin you have a bug on your think. You think +1 but you never add it :)

Comment: i hate chores. here ya go pal.

Comment: @Ragims Ragimovs Note that JavaScript approach will let the user see all hidden questions in the source of the page, so if that's not acceptable then the UpdatePanel approach is the best here.

Comment: @Aristos I'll give u +1 too =)

Comment: @Ragims, use jQuery ajax and webservices instead. UpdatePanel is so passe in my opinion.